# How to increase the size of tab bar?

Tags: iphone, xcode4.3

Is it possible to increase the size of tab bar? I need to increase the height of tab bar in one of my projects!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
CGRect viewFrame = yourTabBar.frame;
viewFrame.size.height = 20;
self.tabBar.frame = viewFrame;
```

Answer (score 1):

or...

```
[self.tabBarPropertyName setFrame:CGRectMake(
    self.tabBarPropertyName.frame.origin.x,
    self.tabBarPropertyName.frame.y-(20),
    self.tabBarPropertyName.frame.size.width,
    self.tabBarPropertyName.frame.height+20)];
```